# What is the probability that a best of seven series goes to the seventh game with negative binomial

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, geometric-distribution

Why cant we use negative binomial to calculate the probability of getting a 7th game in best of 7 game series? 
P(X=7, r=4) = {7-1 C 4 -1} * (.5)^(7-4) * (.5)^4 = .15 , so there is 15 % chance of 7 trails to get 4 success or 15% chance its a 7 game series. 
Another way to look at this would be : Binomial , you need exactly 3 wins in 6 games to go to 7 game series, so that puts Binomial (n=6,x=3)= .31, so there is 31% chance that there is a 7 game series. 
Why don't they come out equal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Summary: the negative-binomial based approach in the question ignores that either team can win Game 7. After correcting for this the results agree.

#### Assumption

Not explicitly stated in the question, but it seems we are assuming the games are iid. with probability 0.5 for either team to win (a sequence of fair coin flips).

#### The probability of Game 7 happening, using the negative binomial distribution

The series goes to Game $7$ if and only if either team obtains its $4$th win in the $7$th game. The events "A wins $4$th time in Game $7$`"  and "B wins $4$th time in Game $7$" are mutually exclusive, so 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(\textrm{Game $7$ is played}) = \\ \mathbb{P}(\textrm{A obtain its $4$th win in the $7$th game}) +  \mathbb{P}(\textrm{B obtains its $4$th win in the $7$th game}).
\end{equation}

Each term on the right-hand-side is the probability of the case team obtaining $4$th wins after $3$ losses. Or, equivalently, the probability of the losing team winning (exactly) $3$ games before the $4$th loss. As reasoned in the question, this is the probability of $3$ in a negative-binomial distribution with parameters $p=0.5,~r=4$ (where $r$ is the number of failures). Thus, the total probability

\begin{equation}
= 2 {4+3-1 \choose 3 }\,0.5^4\,0.5^3  \approx 0.31,
\end{equation}
 exactly the same answer as derived in the question using the binomial distribution.

#### Additional remark

With a general series played to $r$ wins going to $2r-1$th game, the approaches can be seen to give the same result: the binomial coefficient is the same and the factor $2$ in the negative-binomial approach cancels one $0.5$ factor. This cancellation is very closely related to the fact that the binomial distribution approach "naturally" ignores the result of the final game while in the negative-binomial distribution approach both cases need to be taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

The negative binomial would be appropriate if you wanted to know how many games it would take before team A won 4 games.  However, that might be, say, 104 games, in which case team B would have won 100 games.  Obviously that's not the way an actual seven game series works!

Your calculation - $P(X=7 | r=4)$ - using the negative binomial distribution calculates the probability that team B would have won exactly 3 games before team A wins 4, given that team B might have won any number of games before team A wins 4.  It ignores the possibility that team B is the one that wins 4 games first and the impossibility of either team winning 5 or more games.

Comment: The key point here is that the negative binomial does not truncate at 7 and success has to be unambiguous.  That is if success is a win for team A then a win for team B must be a failure.

Comment: Forgetting about the negative binomial the actual result would depend on the probability that team A wins a single game.  Should it be 0.5?  Are the results for one game independent of the others?

Comment: I think the part about 100 games / impossibility of winning $5$ or more games is misleading. The binomial random variable for the $6$ first games can get equally impossible values, such as $5$ wins for team A. Meanwhile, the negative-binomial computation gives the correct probability for "what is the probability that team A wins the series in Game 7" even though "that's not the way an actual seven game series works" - so the only issue is that it does not take into account that the other team is allowed to win Game 7, too.

Comment: As a thought experiment, imagine the teams play (an infinite sequence of) exhibition games after the series is over  and define the case event as Game 7 being part of the actual series. Nothing changes if the exhibition games are then cancelled

Comment: @JuhoKokkala I don't see why the part about 100 games... is misleading, since its intent was to support the explanation of why the N.B. wasn't appropriate.  Basically:  here's when it would be appropriate, here is a specific example of when it would be appropriate, see how this situation doesn't satisfy the real-world conditions of your example.  Flip it around; if the outcome A wins 4 and B wins 100 was in fact within the set of possibilities, which it would be if the objective was as stated in the initial sentence, we wouldn't be using a different distribution in the (3,3) case.

Comment: I still don't understand. Do you agree that the N.B. is fully appropriate here if you want to know the probability that it takes 7 games for team A to win 4 games? And thus fully appropriate for the actual question as long as you add the probability that it takes 7 games for team B to win 4 games? To me, this answer sounds to claim that the probability that the $r$th failure occurs after exactly $k$ successes (for fixed $r,k$)  cannot be computed using the negative-binomial pmf if  the experiment is stopped after $N>k$ successes.

Comment: @jbowman If they play 104 games, A wins 4 games, winning their 4th game in the 7th game, and B wins 100 games, then A wins the best-of-7 series.

Comment: @JiK - If you use the Negative Binomial, however, you are calculating the probability of B winning 100 games *before* A wins the 4th.  So A doesn't win the 7th with its 4th win, A wins the 104th with its 4th win.  If A wins the 7th, that corresponds to the NB probability for $x=3$ (or $x=7$, depending on the formulation.)  That's what NB probabilities are for.  My point is, and you agree, I believe, that the unvarnished NB is not the appropriate distribution to use for the OP's problem.  Whether or not the Binomial is was not an issue I addressed.

Comment: @jbowman _" My point is, and you agree, I believe, that the unvarnished NB is not the appropriate distribution to use for the OP's problem."_ No, I don't agree. The situation in OP's problem is equivalent to playing an infinite number of games and asking the probability that the 7th game is the 4th win for either team, i.e., one team has won 3 games when the other team wins its 4th game. That's *precisely* what the negative binomial distribution is for (if you sum both team's probabilities separately).

Comment: @JiK - it's not an infinite number of games, because the series stops after 7!  With the NB, there is a nonzero probability of the series going 8, 10, 1000 games, and that affects the calculation of the probability of it going 7 games.  The NB *specifies* the number of games *one* of the teams wins.  You can see the NB is not correct from the OP's calculations and your own, I really think we have to agree to disagree at this point :)

Comment: @jbowman Please note that I used the word *equivalent*, so your first sentence doesn't answer to that. Please read JuhoKokkala's comment "As a thought experiment...". And yes, *we have specified that one team wins 4 games* and ask the probability that the other team wins 3 games during that time, that's the whole point. OP's only error is that he only considers team A winning the 7th game and not B so you must double the probability, see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/316600/60164).

Comment: @jbowman it's unclear to me whether we disagree about the math or about something else. Is the following statement true or false? For $k\in \{0,1,2,3\}$, the probability that team A wins the series $4$--$k$ is equal to $P(X=k)$  where $X$ is negative binomial with $p=0.5$, $r=4$ (the version of NB that counts the number of successes before $r$th failure).

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the results using Permutations.

Let us say the two teams for this 7 game series are A and B.

In how ways A or B can be placed as winners in each of the 7 games?
2^7

For illustration purpose, we can depict the winning team for each game with a letter like the following,

A A B B A B A 
A A B B A B B

Now, it is clear that for game to go till 7th game, one of the teams have to
lose 3 times and must win on the 7th game.

What are the possible permutations?

Let's take for A,

B A B B A A **A** (This is one of the series that went to the 7th game and A won it) 
B A B A B A **B** (This is one of the series that went to the 7th game and B won it)

That means how many possible combinations can happen for A and B?
2*C(6,3)

Probability of 7th game happening = # games that can go upto 7 / Total possible number of games

= 2*C(6,3)/2^7
= 0.31